# cakephp: cake bake created no validation rules, why?

Tags: validation, cakephp, cakephp-bake

I used the `cake bake model all`, with my db (cakephp 1.3) which created all models with associations, but no validation rules were created. why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Database you need to remove/disable 'ALLOW NULL' for any column for which you want validation before baking.

Comment: thanks! finally, the reason . usually i build my tables manually. this time i used the mysqlworkbench which created the fields with null allowed.
a question: where can i find documentation about the cake command? (and an offline version of the book)